# DatabaseSchemaUpdater bug on WP7

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, versioning

I have implemented some db versioning logic using DatabaseSchemaUpdater and found one issue.

If i execute this code

```
 updater.DatabaseSchemaVersion = updater.DatabaseSchemaVersion + new Random().Next(10)+1;
 updater.Execute();
```

and leave application by **back button** - everything is OK. Schema version is modified.

If i leave by **Start** button and then start application again (to my mind rather usual case for usual user) - nothing is updated. The db has previous version.

calling Dispose() will fix that issue, but we use a singleton DataContext object so this approach will be a bit hacky for that case.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wfyvwvjd12wifgl/DBUpdTest.zip - Test project - you can simply start the app, and close in different ways and see what happens(db ver is written in textboxes).

The questions are: Is this behavior normal? Does deactivating and starting app again breakes something else? Is there any way to workaround such things(except for Disposing) ?

Comment: Why not use a new DataContext for the Updater? And call it with "using"

Comment: Sure, we can do it. But i would say this is a hack. And not documented anywhere. Would be nice to understand the nature of that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for the last couple of hours and I searched Google a lot. The only solution that helped me was in fact to use the using keyword on the database context. Directly afterwards, I recreated the data context.

```
// _dataContext is static. By checking for null I make sure that the database
// creation and migration is only done once during the app lifecycle
if (_dataContext == null)
{
    // get the context
    using (_dataContext = new WorkTimesDataContext(IsoStoreDatabasefile))
    {
        // do DB creation
        // do DB migration
    }
    // now that the context is disposed, recreate it
    _dataContext = new WorkTimesDataContext(IsoStoreDatabasefile);
}
```

It seems that the database is not updated correctly when the app goes into the tombstoning state although the official documentation clearly states: "When that method (Execute) is called, all changes are submitted to the local database as a single transaction, **including version updates**."

Comment: I use this solution too :)

Answer (score 0):

your missing your tombstoning, That will allow you to backup data to your Isolated Storage.

It is highly needed when working with data on the windows phone. The Link below should be enough to get your head around how it works and how to easily implement it into your application.

[Tombstoning Video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Video/gg508694)

Comment: erm.... I don't actually understand what do u mean. What exactly should i tombstone and at what moment of time should i restore it and how would it help in my case. Can you fix the attached project by adding tombstoning ?

Comment: in the process that you read and watch the above video, you will learn what tombstoning is and where and how to use it. it is very important in the production of a windows phone application that i don't feel it right to just give you the answer but for you to learn it and solve it.

Comment: Voting this answer down when it is correct is rude, also for voting it down for not blatantly giving you an answer because your lazy. Tombstoning is one of the biggest things to learn on the windows phone, if you don't know it you shouldn't be developing for the Windows Mobile phones.Also if you expect everyone to always give you direct answers your never going to get anywhere, meaning your in the wrong field of work. I'm going to Flag this question, note all of this for future Reference, when someone is nice enough to give an answer, you respect that!

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve my problem and doesn't give any help to solving. The reference you gave me doesn't help with updating DB version in any way.

Comment: Your not backing up your data in the Database to isolated storage which in return in resetting your data every time you leave your application. My answer will solve that if you did some work.

Comment: So why don't u fix the project and show me that the problem is in tombstoning ? I say that the problem is not in tombstoning. If u think that im wrong, fix the project. I think u don't even understand what im talking about in my question.

Comment: your looking for someone to do the work for you and that's not what this site does. Your problem will be answered, and i wont argue about it. In the process i suggest looking into Tombstoning, if not that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem, because I had the beta version of the WP7 SDK. It fixed itself once I installed the non beta version.